# Simplified Collection initialization

Tags: c#, collections, initialization

While initializing WF4 activities we can do something like this:

```
Sequence s = new Sequence()
{
    Activities = {
        new If() ...,
        new WriteLine() ...,
    }
}
```

Note that `Sequence.Activities` is a `Collection<Activity>` but it can be initialized without the new *Collection()*.

How can I emulate this behaviour on my `Collection<T>` properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any collection that has an `Add()` method and implements `IEnumerable` can be initialized this way.  For details, refer to [Object and Collection Initializers for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).  (The lack of the new `Collection<T>` call is due to an object initializer, and the ability to add the items inline is due to the collection initializer.)

The compiler will automatically call the `Add()` method on your class with the items within the collection initialization block.

---

As an example, here is a very simple piece of code to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        this.Collection = new Collection<int>();
    }

    public Collection<int> Collection { get; private set; }

    public static void Main()
    {

        // Note the use of collection intializers here...
        Test test = new Test
            {
                Collection = { 3, 4, 5 }
            };


        foreach (var i in test.Collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }  
}
```

Comment: ... and which implements IEnumerable :)

Comment: @Jon: Very true - I edited to be more explicit.  (I tend to always implement IEnumerable on a "collection", but that is really not a requirement ;) )

Comment: Yes but my collection is using `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` which already implements IEnumerable and has an Add() method. The true is, it doesn't give any compilation error but it seems empty while iterating through it.

Comment: Moreover, the link that you gave does not exemplifies this type of initialization.

Comment: @Jota: It actually is the link that shows how this works.  I just put up some working sample code to demonstrate.  Try out the program above - it uses collection initializers with `Collection<T>` to handle this scenario exactly.

Comment: @Reed-Copsey My mistake. I was doing the initialization on the getter itself. Something like: `get { return (myCollection != null ? myCollection : new Collection<int>()); }`. If I do it on the constructor it works as intended.