# How do I create a hardcoded List?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplified Collection initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793286/simplified-collection-initialization)

I have the string values, I just want to set them in a list. Something like -

```
List<string> tempList = List<string>();
tempList.Insert(0,"Name",1,"DOB",2,"Address");
```

I guess I am having a brain freeze :)

Comment: you mean adding multiple element using single statement/

Comment: Provided sample will not even compile since Insert has only 2params.

Comment: Waqas - Yes, that was what I was looking for. djacobson - Apologies, I just had a freeze and figure I would get a quick help answer.

Comment: @Tomas - Consider that he wants "something like" his code.

Comment: @TomasVoracek: It was not supposed to compile...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
var tempList = new List<string> { "Name", "DOB", "Address" };
```

With the collection initializer syntax, you don't even need the explicit calls to `Add()` or `Insert()`. The compiler will put them there for you.

The above declaration is actually compiled down to:

```
List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
tempList.Add("Name");
tempList.Add("DOB");
tempList.Add("Address");
```

Comment: @Marlon You would think so, but consider that what's is really happening is that you're calling the default constructor, and then adding a bunch of items. It's also legal to say `new List<string>(16) { "OneItem" }`, which would contruct the list with capacity 16 and a single stored item. I guess the designers assumed that since you knew how many items there were, you could always just put the number in yourself.

Answer (score 6):

You can initialize a list with data like so:

`var list = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "baz" };`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use AddRange which would accomplish the same thing if the list already exists:

```
List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
tempList.AddRange( new string[] {"Name", "DOB", "Address"} );
```